# How can I transfer tokens using RPC?

Tags: rpc, transfer

The [RPC documentation](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference) doesn't list any functions for transferring tokens. How can I do this using RPC?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following link. 
https://steemit.com/eos/@noprom/using-eos-rpc-api-to-transfer-eos

Answer (score 1):

Most simple way is using Js library for rpc.
Alternatively, you can see [JavaWrapper](https://github.com/EOSEssentials/eos-java-rpc-wrapper) (this is old realisation, but I see this)